# IntelliJ IDEA svn doesn't ignore .iml files

Tags: intellij-idea

In Settings-Version Control-Ignored Files, I have already specified the mask `*.iml`.

[image]

However, when I click on **Commit Changes** (Ctrl+K), `.iml` files still appear in the change list. In the right-click menu of one of these`.iml` files, I see the "ignore..." button is disabled.

How do I ignore these? It is annoying having to uncheck all these files every time I make a commit. 
[image]

Comment: Have these files already been 'added'? If so, then you'll have to unadd them before your configured 'ignore' can be applied. You might also consider adding a global SVN ignore for `*.iml` e.g. edit your local Subversion config file and add `*.iml` to 'global-ignores' (on Linux your locla config file is `~/.subversion/config`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue color means Modified - so the files are already under VCS. And it is possible to ignore only unversioned files.

So what you need is to remove the files from VCS first (using `git rm --cached`, if you use git, `svn rm --keep-local` for svn, etc), commit the removal (BTW, be sure to do this outside of the IDE), and then they will be properly ignored.